# How to create a Desktop Entry that executes a bash script inside the terminal?

Tags: shell-script, manjaro, .desktop

**How to create a Desktop Entry that executes a bash script inside the terminal by clicking in a shell file?**

*Note*: I don't want to open a specified terminal, but the default system terminal shell instead.

I tried using this file (Open with `gnome-terminal`, but I prefer to open with the default one), but with no success:

```ini
[Desktop Entry]
...etc...
Exec=gnome-terminal -- bash -c "'%u'"
...etc...
```

I'm using Manjaro.

Exemple of I'm trying to do:

1. Click on a Bash file using the file explorer
2. Select "Open with..." and "Execute as Shell Script"
3. A new terminal window opens
4. Conclusion: Instead of typing `./filename`, I just double-click in the file

Comment: *"..., but with no success:"*. Readers will need more evidence as to what you *DID* try AND what was the result (error message?) . Otherwise you're expecting we can read your mind, right? (-;!

Answer (score 0):

You should read the launcher documentation at freedesktop.org.
%u represents a singe URL, so the term

> "'%u'"

isn't a valid bash command (even if %u is expanded behind the quoting).
From your comments I don't believe you need or want a gui terminal session, so the gnome-terminal stuff seems unnecessary.

I'll suggest you create an executable shell script (say /usr/local/bin/myfunction) then edit the launcher (a texdt file) to read
...

```
Exec=/usr/local/bin/myfunction
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I want a GUI session.
It should use gnome-terminal or xfce4-terminal

Comment: I'm trying
`exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator bash -c "cd $(dirname '%f'); bash '%u'; echo Process ended, press CTRL and C to exit.; sleep infinity"`
without success.

Comment: Now i'm trying
`exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator bash -c "dir=\"%f\" && cd \"\$(dirname \"\$dir\")\" && export CURRENT_DIR=\"\$(pwd -P)\" && bash \"\$CURRENT_DIR/\$(basename \"\$dir\")\"; echo Process ended, press CTRL and C to exit.; sleep infinity"`
But i'm getting this error:
`bash: '/home/user/mydocs/script': Inexistent file or directory
Process ended, press CTRL and C to exit.`

Comment: The %f has no meaning (isn't substituted)  when you execute that from a command line.

Comment: How to put "%f" argument from .desktop into the command line content? I want to specify the %f file path.